# how do I access the array string returned by jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I have the following code that searches the characters typed in the search box with the onkeyup event.

```
$("#keywords").keyup(function () {
    var kw = $("#keywords").val();
    if (kw != '') {
        var url = "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/simpromotions/livesearch/';?>" + kw;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                **alert(data);**
                $.each(data,function(ptitle, category){
                    $("#results").html('<label>'+ptitle+': '+category+'</label><br>');
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        $("#results").html("");
        return false;
    }
});
```

In the above code when I alert the `data` it displayes the following array string.

```
{"pcode":"22","category":"NightTalk","ptitle":"HourlyNightTalk"}
```

I cant seem to access the `pcode`, `category` and `ptitle` as I have done in the next line. (after alert)
Please help me how I can access the three!

Comment: You should perhaps consider using Knockout.js in this case. With that you can easily bind your Json/viewmodel data to UI elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means `data` is a string, and the response is a simple JSON encoded object, not an array.

You have to parse the response first. You can let jQuery do this for you by fixing the `dataType` property:

```
dataType: "json" // dataType, not datatype
```

Inside the callback, `data` will be a JavaScript object now and you just directly access its properties (learn more about objects in [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)):

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#results").html('<label>'+data.ptitle+': '+data.category+'</label><br>');
}
```

It doesn't make sense to use `$.each` here. [Have a look at the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to learn what it does and how it works.

---

You mentioned that sometimes you actually get an array back. In that case you probably want to use `$.each`. To make your code simpler, I recommend to **always** return an array from  the server:

```
var $results = $('#results');
$results.empty();
$.each(data, function(i, obj){ 
    $results.append('<label>'+obj.ptitle+' is in '+obj.category+'</label><br>'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the property. Try this:

```
alert(data.ptitle)
```

or, in your case

```
$("#results").html('<label>'+data.ptitle+': '+data.category+'</label><br>');
```

**example** http://jsfiddle.net/CcJEX/

Comment: alert(data.ptitle); --> it results undefined!

Comment: why are you calling each on data? is an array?

Comment: Yes, for some characters the search result is as follows:[{"pcode":"3","category":"Category_1","ptitle":"ads"},
 {"pcode":"18","category":"Category_1","ptitle":"ddddd"},
 {"pcode":"22","category":"Category_1","ptitle":"asdfa"}]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you misunderstood jQuery's `each()` function. The prototype of the callback function is `function(index, value)` where index will be "pcode", "category", "ptitle" and value will be "22", "NightTalk", "HourlyNightTalk" respectively.

Comment: But there are several section of results as follows: [{"pcode":"3","category":"Category_1","ptitle":"ads"},
 {"pcode":"18","category":"Category_1","ptitle":"ddddd"},
 {"pcode":"22","category":"Category_1","ptitle":"asdfa"}]