# how to access to what jquery ajax returns as an array

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

following is the value of the varaible `data` :

```
[{"pcode":"1","category":"Category_1","ptitle":"Title_1"},
 {"pcode":"2","category":"Category_2","ptitle":"Title_2"}, 
 {"pcode":"3","category":"Category_1","ptitle":"Title_3"}]
```

My jquery ajax function return the above array. and I use the below code to list the details of them on the page.

```
$.each(data,function(ptitle,category){
    $("#results").empty().append('<label>'+data.ptitle+' is in '+data.category+'</label><br>');
});
```

What I want to display using my code above is  like:

```
Title_1 is in Category_1
Title_2 is in Category_2
Title_3 is in Category_1
```

but all is displayed is:

```
undefined: undefined
```

Comment: I mentioned that you should have a look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to learn how `$.each` works. The callback accepts to two arguments, the index of the element in the array and the element itself. So it should be something like this: `function(i, obj){ $("#results").append('<label>'+obj.ptitle+' is in '+obj.category+'</label><br>'); });`. I will update my answer to your previous question. Instead of asking a new question, you should have updated your previous question.

Comment: maybe the problem could also be the asynchronous call..

Comment: @steo: Have a look at the OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021216/how-do-i-access-the-array-string-returned-by-jquery-ajax-function). It's not a problem with the call itself.

Comment: @FelixKling ok , great! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#results").empty();
$.each(data, function(index, element){
    $("#results").append('<label>'+element.ptitle+' is in '+element.category+'</label><br>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, first parameter for `each` is item index and the second one is the item itself. Also, it is a bad idea to empty `results` container in each iteration.

```
var resultsContainer = $("#results");
resultsContainer.empty();
$.each(data, function(index, item){
    resultsContainer.append('<label>'+item.ptitle+' is in '+item.category+'</label><br>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[have a look at the docs.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) the callback uses the parameters index and value, do it like:

```
$.each(data, function(i, elem) {
    $("#results").empty().append('<label>'+elem.ptitle+' is in '+elem.category+'</label><br>');
});
```

Comment: The `.empty()` call doesn't make sense here though ;)